# Android Youtube : how to get youtube channel playlist and upload data in single request

Tags: android, youtube

I want to get complete channel information of user like playlist, activity, uploads, favourites and other channel info using single request.
The url in the `<content src >` tag inside the channel subscription entry  is returning **Http 403 forbidden,** when I'm passing "events "

```
 {content type='application/atom+xml;type=feed'
   src='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/trustnordisk/events?v=2'/>}
```

But if I pass uploads / playlists / favourites in the below url, it's working.

```
    {content type='application/atom+xml;type=feed' 
rc='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/littlet2009/uploads?v=2'/>
```

But, my requirement is to get the complete information (playlists /fav / uploads etc ) in one single request, is it possible?